# SQL DeadLock Example

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Can one explain if this is a good example of a dead lock on SQL Stored Procedure?

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION MergeAccount

MERGE INTO Name AS TARGET
USING (
    SELECT @accountId, @playerName, @lastSeenDateTime
) AS SOURCE (
    [AccountId], [Name], [LastSeenDateTime]
) 
ON TARGET.[AccountId] = SOURCE.[AccountId] 
AND 
(
    SELECT TOP 1 [Name] 
    FROM [Name] 
    WHERE [AccountId] = @AccountId 
    ORDER BY [LastSeenDateTime] DESC
) = SOURCE.[Name]
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (
        [AccountId], [Name], [LastSeenDateTime]
    ) VALUES (
        [AccountId], [Name], [LastSeenDateTime]
    )
WHEN MATCHED AND SOURCE.LastSeenDateTime > TARGET.LastSeenDateTime THEN 
    UPDATE
    SET TARGET.LastSeenDateTime = SOURCE.LastSeenDateTime
;

COMMIT TRANSACTION MergeAccount
```

For example, if you check the SELECT statement in the WHERE clause, I am actually asking for data in the same table of the same user.

Should I create a DECLARE and accept the data into a var outside then apply the where clause?

Is this bad practice to write a query as such?

Comment: Deadlocks happen between *different* sessions, not in one statement of one session. (Excepting the occasional rare intra-statement deadlock with parallelism; those are considered bugs. `MERGE` has indeed seen a few such bugs.) Do you actually have deadlocks you're trying to solve, or is this a hypothetical concern?

Comment: Here's a similar scenario, with a good explanation: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23467/merge-statement-deadlocking-itself.  Per @JeroenMostert though; this requires there to be a competing, second session.

Comment: @JeroenMostert This is a valid concern as I am having issue.  The program is reporting its on this Stored Procedure.  Even though very basic, there is competing going on with other sessions (we run many bots of same application).  Not even sure how to simplify it as its already pretty simple.

Comment: This stored procedure will be the deadlock victim; by itself, that is not sufficient information to diagnose and fix the deadlock, because you also need to know what the other statement looks like. It could be another copy of the same `MERGE` statement, or it could be something else. Capture a deadlock trace using Profiler or Extended Events, or check the existing buffer (https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10644/deadlock-error-isnt-returning-the-deadlock-sql).

Comment: For your particular scenario, it looks like `MERGE` isn't really buying you anything in terms of simpler or faster queries. You can split it up in a classic insert-where-not-exists/update pattern. That also allows you to apply finer-grained locking.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to analyze the whole DeadLock scenario and are able to reproduce it.

I suggest you to run `SQL Server Profiler` with the `TSQL_Locks` model.

If a deadlock happens, the `DeadLock graph` column will be filled with a nice way to analyze your problem.